# Might or may for things that didn't happen

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, might, could

Collins dictionary says you can only use might or could in this situation- when something didn't happen but you think it could have.

So, sentence 1 is right and sentence 2 is wrong.

1. `If he hadn't hurt his ankle, he might/could have won the race'
2. `If he hadn't hurt his ankle, he may have won the race'

Do people make that distinction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Might* is the past form of *may.* Thus, it would be wrong to use may in the third conditional since your second sentence expresses a situation which is not 'real'.

In addition to Collins Dictionary, English Grammar in Use explains it (p.60) as well:

'We use might (not may) when the situation is not real'.

Please note the difference:

- If we had a garden, we could (not can) have a cat.
- If I hadn't been ill, I would have (not will have) gone to the party
- If he hadn't hurt his ankle, he might (not may) have won the race.

The example sentences are taken from [British Council Website](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/conditionals-1)

**In short, yes, people make this distinction.**

Comment: It's not uncommon for journalists to use sentences like (2), but it always strikes me as glaringly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: `If he hadn't hurt his ankle, he **might/could** have won the race' (NOT 'may have')

When we talk about the past, we use **if + had.**.. The sentence (If he... race) refers to the past. We can use 'might', not 'may'. 'Might' is the past form of 'may'.

`If he hadn't hurt his ankle, he **could** have won the race.' (he would have been able to win)

`If he hadn't hurt his ankle, he **might** have won the race.' (Perhaps he would have won)